Blazor WebApp project
When i create a new Blazor web app project, it asks me to select interactive render mode, if i select Auto(Server and WebAssembly), it creates 2 projects, 1 for server, 1 for client.
It seems server project has razor pages, client project has razor pages, so, what is the difference then? What kind of code needs to be placed inside the server project, what kind of code should be placed inside the client project.
If i have a API method that returns list of cities, that api method, should be added as a controller inside server project (CityController.cs and method GetCities)? The client project then injects HTTP service and makes a call to that GetCities?
While i get the server project uses server side rendering via signal-R, i am trying to understand in low level, kind of code that goes into each project (in other words, in what use case one should use server, webassembly or Auto rendering mode options?)
For example, if i want to build a dashboard that displays grids, charts data from an API method(s) and api method need to be created part of this, what type of blazor project needs to be created.

A comprehensive answer to this question is beyond the scope of an SO answer - the subject is too broad and complex.  You need to review the Microsoft documentation on the subject - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-8.0.  I've also written a couple of personal commentaries.   Here are the links - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazor.Interactivity/blob/master/Interactivity.md and https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazor.ExploreRendering/blob/master/Documents/Going-For-Broke.md.

A page could be set to 4 rendermodes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0 . 
SSR(also called prerender) pages need to be processed in the "server project".
InteractiveServer(uses SignalR ,when disable prerender) pages need to be processed in the "server project".
InteractiveWebAssembly(when disable prerender) pages need to be processed in the "client project".
InteractiveAuto(when disable prerender) pages need to processed in both "server project" and "client project".
First thing to clarify is the "server project" has a dependency reference to the "client project", So Server could use all pages resources in the client. So you could surely place all rendermode pages in "client project".

But by contrast, you cannot put InteractiveWebAssembly and InteractiveAuto pages in the server project. Because "client project" doesn't have dependenty reference to "server project". So only SSR and IneractiveServer pages can be put in "server project".
"The client project then injects HTTP service and makes a call to that GetCities?"
You are right, you could add controllers in the "server project" and just like webapi program. The pages in "InteractiveWebassembly" mode could be treated as pure "front-end" to fetch your back-end api.  Services need to be registered in the "processing project" depending on the rendermode. Of course, an auto mode page need to register service in both project.
"in what use case one should use server, webassembly or Auto rendering mode options?"
For fast developing, I will choose servermode. If you choose at the beginning, there 's only 1 server project. You needn't to care about the front-back fethcing issues.  The disadvantages is the signalR consume hardware when too many users visiting. And it need better network, sometimes user may occur "signalR disconnected" problem.

WebAssembly doesn't consume server hardware so it could take more users. But the fisrt loading time is anonying.
Auto mode is to solve both side problem. It uses servermode until webassembly resources finished download. For your needs, I recommand you use Auto mode.
You could check how the rendermode changes in a page like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78180059/20240963
besides, be careful about if you have global rendermode in App.razor.
